# DeclareSIUnit failed

Tags: siunitx

It seems that the dtx-file-contained `\ul` (for `\micro\litre`) doesn't work on my machine `Undefined control sequence`

I have tried to install from the `.dtx`, the .ins and the `tds.zip` files, all from the latest versions of `l3` and `siunitx` packages with no success.

I have solved the problem for `\ul`-kind of declarations (see `\molar` in the mwe) but I'm trying to `\DeclareSIUnit\Molar{\textsc{m}}`
which won't do the trick.

Here's a mwe:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{siunitx}

    \newcommand{\molar}{\mole\per\cubic\deci\meter}

    \begin{document}

    % (Ugly but) Works fine
    \SI{2}{\molar}.

    % Doesn't work, although DeclareSIUnit \ul {\micro\litre} is in siunitx.dtx...
    \SI{2}{\ul}

    \end{document}
```

If anyone asks me to do a `\listfile`, I'd be much obliged to but haven't succeeded (and G**gle hasn't been my friend neither), so a mwe would be helpful)

Comment: You need to load the `abbriviations` module. Please read the manual.

Comment: Which version of `siunitx` do you have? Please add `\listfiles` tou your input and edit the resulting `File list` from your `.log` into the question. To be clear, this works for me with the latest release.

Comment: Wanted to give the \litsfile in the original post, but couldn't find how to: tried to put \listfile between \begin...\end{document} and before that. No clue of where else it can go. Should I runtex on the

Comment: The command is `\listfiles`, not `\listfile`, and must be put in the preamble, i.e. _before_ `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Thanks! So...
As for everybody else with this problem: old version.

Problem is: I still have downloaded the latest files (checked the included siunitx manual's date)!

Is there, by any chance, an alternative to 1) downloading the *.tds.zip or 2) compiling the missing_packages.ins ?
(I'm running a Debian so tlmgr is not really an option... Yeah I know FML)

Comment: Problem solved: I believe it came from a conflict with older versions of `*sty` files.

So, when using `~/texmf/tex/latex/customd_stuff`, DO NOT extract the `.tds.zip` archives directly in `~/texmf/`: you'll just get things mixed up!

Comment: @Maugan Things should extract correctly into `~/texmf`, but this depends on your zip program. As this is an 'old version' issue, I'll close the question (the 'usual policy' on this type of issue).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue solved by correctly installing the latest version of the package.
